# -bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory #10

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I have no 'sudo' privilege.
When I run

```
printf '\n%s\n%s\n%s' '# virtualenv' 'export WORKON_HOME=~/virtualenvs' 
'source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh' >> ~/.bashrc
```

it shows error:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory
```

how to solve this problem? Can anyone give some advises?

Comment: How have you installed `virtualenvwrapper`?

Comment: yes, I have installed virtualenvwrapper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without `sudo` or any other way to raise privileges you don't have write access to `/usr/local/bin/` so you cannot install `virtualenvwrapper.sh` there. [Download](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper) a distribution, extract it and copy `virtualenvwrapper.sh` to a directory where you have write access. Edit your `.bashrc` to source `virtualenvwrapper.sh` from that directory.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue because pip installed `virutalenvwrapper` into `~/.local`.

You can change its path in `.bashrc`:

```sh
source $HOME/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```