# When i open terminal, it always print these error code

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenvwrapper

When i open terminal, it always print these code.
How can i delete these?
It is python3

[image: img]

```
-bash: expert: command not found
-bash: souce/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/46907827/5644965

Comment: this issue is not related to django or python. better change your relevant tag

Comment: Check your `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` files. Are you missing a space after `source`?

Comment: thx everyone forgive me for reply very slow. I forgot type a space after source. I don't notice.

Comment: You are welcome, Fumihiro san. どういたしまして

Answer (score 3):

Ok, your terminal is using a shell called `bash`. Bash loads some files when you start it. At one of these files there is a line that seems to be lacking a space between the word `source` and the path to load the `virtualenvwrapper.sh` script:

```
source/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

The above shoud be:

```
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Some files bash load at startup are `.profile`, `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` and so on. Perhaps someone edited one of these recently and deleted the space by mistake.

Comment: Thx I got a mistake. but now I don't know how can i solve this and how i can change the mistake. I can't find out the file....

Comment: sonfumihironoMacBook-puro:~ sonfumihiro$ source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: You must edit the file containing the "source" call and add a space after the word `source`. The file should be at `/Users/sonfumihiro/.bashrc` or something like that in a Mac.